# How to convert array to string and vice versa?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, string

How to convert a array <-> string?

I've a bi dimensional array and i need to save to database and retrieve.

```
Dim myarray(,) as string = {{"some","some"},{"some","some"}}
```

Comment: Are you committed to using an array? There might be some more options available if you used generic collections like `List(Of List(Of String))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) cannot serialize multi-dimentional arrays (`String(,)`), itcan serialize jagged arrays (`String()()`). So, if you are willing to use an "array of array of strings" instead of a "two-dimensional array of string", you can use the XmlSerializer.

Example of how to serialize (imports `System.Xml.Serialization` and `System.IO`):

```
    Dim myarray()() As String = { _
        New String() {"some", "some"}, _
        New String() {"some", "some"}}

    Dim s As New XmlSerializer(GetType(String()()))
    Dim stream As New StringWriter()
    s.Serialize(stream, myarray)

    Dim myString = stream.ToString()
```

`myString` then contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ArrayOfString>
    <string>some</string>
    <string>some</string>
  </ArrayOfString>
  <ArrayOfString>
    <string>some</string>
    <string>some</string>
  </ArrayOfString>
</ArrayOfArrayOfString>
```

Likewise, to deserialize, you can use `s.Deserialize`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a StringBuilder and iterate through the array using a marker of some sort, such as a semi-colon to indicate the pairs and a dash to indicate the string in the pair i.e. `some-some`, and write out the `StringBuilder.ToString()` i.e. `some-some;some-some` to the database. Then when you read from the database a string in this fashion and simply rebuild the array by using the markers to separate out the elements from the string itself.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.